# LWJGL vertex shader gl_PointSize not working

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl, glpointsize

I'm trying to change the size of a point in a vertex shader in LWJGL and can't get it to work. The point size is always 1px if I try to change it from the shader.

Vertex shader:

```
void main(){
   gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*gl_Vertex;
   gl_PointSize = 10.0;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
void main(){
   gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
}
```

Draw code:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, p_vbo);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, c_vbo);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, particles_num);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

My aim is to dynamically change the point size, but I can't change the point size from the shader. If I call this code:

```
glPointSize(10.0f);
```

from java, the size gets changed, but I want to be able to do that for each point. I've enabled my shader to change point sizes with:

```
glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
```

Just to clarify: I can render all my points and everything is working great, but the point size is always 1px. I'm also not using smooth points.

EDIT: 
glGetFloat(GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE) returns 1.0, which should indicate that my hardware does not support other pointsizes than 1.0. But if i modify my draw code from:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, particles_num);
```

to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < particles_num; i++) {
   glPointSize(massBuff.get(i));
   glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, i, 1);
}
```

Where massBuff contains random floats with values 1f - 10f, I get the exactly desired result but with lesser performance. So, it's apparently supported by my hardware, and I still want to be able to do this from the shader.

EDIT: 
I also tried:

```
glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
```

Which does not work either. The program is behaving like i never enabled GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE, as it uses glPointSize() if it exists it in the java code. As I understand, all calls to glPointSize() will be ignored if GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE is enabled, and the program expects the shader to set the value, but even so, glPointSize() is used if it exists in the code.

Comment: try calling glGet( GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE ) to see what the biggest supported size on your pc is. source: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPointSize.xml

Comment: glGetFloat(GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE) returns 1.0, damn. But in that case, isn't it strange that I can change the value to 10.0 with glPointSize(10.0f) from java? The points render bigger too, so it should be supported by my hardware, even thou glGet says otherwise... Btw thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, the state you're supposed to glEnable is called `GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE`, not `GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE`. Does this make a difference for you?

Comment: That didn't make a difference. Still not able to change the size from the shader.

Comment: for anyone else running into the issue of `gl_PointSize` being ignored, this worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I faced the issue using OpenGL2ES2.

In the vertex shader, setting the gl_PointSize value had no effect at all.
The lines width, on the contrary, could be specified and it was working.
I'm not sure of the reason of this, but it seems that Points are kinda not well handled / not part of GL2ES2.

Having no way to specify the size of the point but really having to, I had to use a kinda hacky way. I'm not specially proud of this, but this totally does the trick.

The idea is to use lines as point... Yes.
For instance, To have a point of 6px width, at position (X,Y) you just have to draw a line  6px wide from (X-width/2, y) to (X+width/2, y).
Of course, you'll have to adapt the length of the line depending on the distance from the camera / zoom.

As I said, I'm not proud but well, this works even if that doubles the amount of data. Always better than using sprites.

Comment: I agree, that's kind of a hacky solution. I can't see how you get smooth points using glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH) with your solution, but it might work for rectangle points, but then i would just use quads^^ I though in the beginning that you would use a line to specify the first entry data as position and the first of the other two as the size, and then use that in a geometry shader to create a point or something... THAT would have been hacky!

Comment: Aggree with you, it's a very bulky workaround. I needed point for visual debugging, where point smoothing is not necessary.
This still has the benefits of using (a bit) less data than quads and being batchable with my debug lines.